# Search for a country in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I have a list of countries, and I'm trying to center the map and adjust the zoom level to show the whole country in the map.

Using geocoding APIs `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/{dataset}/{query}.json?country={cc}&access_token=<your access token>`, I'm able to get some coordinates that are not quite in the center of the country, but at least I get relevant coordinates, however, the returned object doesn't contain any information on the zoom level.

```
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="at">Austria</option>
    <option value="cy">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="de">Germany</option>
    <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
    <option value="es">Spain</option>
</select>

<div class="map" id="map"></div>

<script>

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'the_access_token';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8', //stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // random starting position
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom level
});

// Find country
$('#country').on('change', function (e) {
    countrycode = $(this).val();
    country = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    console.log(countrycode, country);
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/"+country+".json?country="+countrycode+"&access_token="+mapboxgl.accessToken,
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            map.easeTo({
                center: res.features[0].center,
                // zoom:
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

What am I missing?  Should I be using different APIs?  Or is what I'm looking for not supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's also returned in the response is a bounding box which you can pass to `map.fitBounds` for accurate coordinates + zoom:

```
var bbox = res.features[0].bbox;
map.fitBounds([
  [bbox[0], bbox[1]],
  [bbox[2], bbox[3]]
]);
```

Comment: Perfect, I noticed the bbox in the features, but didn't know what it means or how to use it.  Thanks.